# Show contents of multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, recursion, javascript-objects

Got a small problem here.
I am trying to create a function that shows me the contents of multiple objects.
Therefore i created the following code and it works BUT for some reason it does STOP AFTER the first object and i just don't get it why this is happening :/

```
var space = '-';

function showObjects() {

    for (indexArgument = 0; indexArgument < arguments.length; indexArgument++) {

        for (indexObject in arguments[indexArgument]) {

            console.log(space + indexObject + ' : ' + arguments[indexArgument][indexObject]);

            if ( typeof arguments[indexArgument][indexObject] === 'object') {

                space += '-';
                showObjects( arguments[indexArgument][indexObject] );

            }

        }

    }

}

var object1 = { a : 1, b : 2 , data : { a : 12 } };
var object2 = { a : 6, b : 9 , data : { a : 17 } };

showObjects(object1, object2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **all of your variables are global**.
To make `indexArgument` and `indexObject` local is easy (adding a `var` in front of them) - but to make your code work with the `space` variable you have to restructure your code a little bit.

I would recommend splitting the "arguments" and the "recursive" logic like so:

```
function showObjects() {

    // loop through all arguments and call the recursive function
    for (var indexArgument = 0; indexArgument < arguments.length; indexArgument++) {
        // call the recursive function (with a additional space parameter)
        showObject(arguments[indexArgument], '-');
    }

    // the recursive function 
    // (handles only one object, with the local space variable)
    function showObject(object, space) {
        for (var indexObject in object) {
            console.log(space + indexObject + ' : ' + object[indexObject]);
            if ( typeof object[indexObject] === 'object') {
                // recursive call of this function
                showObject( object[indexObject], space + '-' );
            }
        }
    }

}

var object1 = { a : 1, b : 2 , data : { a : 12 } };
var object2 = { a : 6, b : 9 , data : { a : 17 } };

showObjects(object1, object2);
```

Comment: Great, exactly what i was looking for! Martin Ernst, thank you as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your variables `indexArgument` and `indexObject` local like so:

```
for(var indexArgument = 0; indexArgument < arguments.length; indexArgument++) {

    for (var indexObject in arguments[indexArgument]) {

        /* your code */

    }
}
```